# how to store produced data in database?

Tags: java, mysql, database, apache-kafka, kafka-producer-api

i created a kafka producer on java that works fine, now im trying to store the data produced in an mySQL database but i don't know how. i tried this code but it doesn't work

```
try {
           String MyUrl = "jdbc:mysql://130.2.2.2/pfa";
           Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"); 
           Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(MyUrl, "root", "");
           Statement stm = con.createStatement();
           ResultSet rs = stm.executeQuery("select * from tmp");

           while(rs.next()) {
               producer.send(new ProducerRecord<String, String>("test",rs.getString(1)));
               con.close();
           }
       }catch(Exception e) {System.out.println(e);}
```

any help is much appreciated about sending data to the database

Comment: You need to use insert statement , but I can see there you are using select statement. What you want to insert into the table could you please share the table structure. Check if this helps you ? https://alvinalexander.com/java/java-mysql-insert-example-preparedstatement/

Comment: @HarmandeepSinghKalsi yes i agree but thats what i found and i copy pasted it literally becoz the writer said it worked. i thought the "send" methode is the one responsible for the send tho thats why i didnt change the "select"

Comment: So you've got the data on a Kafka topic, and you want to write it to a database? Or you want to read data from a database into a Kafka topic? Either way, you should probably be using Kafka Connect (which is part of Apache Kafka)

Comment: @RobinMoffatt i want to write to a database

Comment: http://idownvotedbecau.se/itsnotworking/. And you can find plenty of examples online (mostly from Robin) about kafka jdbc sink

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I understand what you're expecting to happen from that code.

1. You're reading from the database, never inserting into it
2. You're closing the database connection after every loop iteration, meaning you'll get an exception that the database is already closed on the second loop, and therefore the resultset might terminate as well (I'm a little fuzzy on if those are lazy objects or not)

Might I suggest that you follow the Deep Dive on the JDBC connector? https://dev.to/rmoff/kafka-connect-jdbc-sink-tips-tricks-video-walkthrough-2egf

> i copy pasted it literally becoz the writer said it worked

This will never be a good way to learn anything. You can read the code and type it all back out, explaining it to yourself as you go... But never blindly copy something that you assume solves your problem

Comment: the question when using an "insert" statement is what to put in the fields after the "values" keyword? meaning how to refer to the items produced by the producer? knowing that i have a perfectly functionning producer on java